# LTC4332 communication issues

Tags: arduino, spi

I have a slight issue with the communication between my Arduino Uno R3 board and an [LTC4332](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC4332.pdf) SPI extender chip. The Arduino is the master and the LTC4332 device is the slave.

The Arduino SPI channels (MOSI, MISO, CLK and CS) are connected to the respective pins on the LTC4332 demo board and I want to talk to the internal registers of this device.

Following the datasheet, I can't seem to get any data out of the device through the MISO line. The SSC pin of the LTC4332 is connected to the CS line of the Arduino Uno R3 and the LTC4332 is set up in local mode.

Has anyone come across this issue? If so, how did you solve it?

Comment: Based on the datasheet, for local mode, other than set SSC to low, the `REMOTE` pin need to connected to GND.